# How to use regex to match all php function parameter names?

Tags: php, regex

I don't have much experience with regex. I'm facing the following problem:
I want to find all parameter names in a method's PHP declaration code.

For instance:

```php
public function foo($param1, $param2, $param3) {}
```

When the regex is applied to this code, it should give me the matches param1, param2 and param3. While trying to solve this problem, I've come to the following regex:

`/\((?:[\,\s\w]*\$(\w+)[\,\s\w]*)+\)/g`

My thoughts have been:

- Declare the delimiters `\(` and `\)`.
- Declare the parameter match group `\$(\w+)`.
- Since it was matching the delimiters immediately:

  - Declare the possibility of getting commas, any white space and any letter(just for the case of typehints) `[\,\s\w]*`
  - Make the above group surround the parameter name group. `[\,\s\w]*\$(\w+)[\,\s\w]*`
  - Declare a non-capturing group of this, so I can say that the whole group can actually appear more than once. `(?:[\,\s\w]*\$(\w+)[\,\s\w]*)+`

Unfortunately I'm not able to match and get all parameters names within the delimiters(brackets). All this regex does is match the entire method's parameter declaration, and on the name group, it's just matching the last one, and that'd be the param3 name.

Could somebody, with more experience than me, give me a help with this little puzzle? I've been using http://regexr.com/. From now, thanks for any help.

Comment: I wonder if it is suitable to use `Reflection` .

Comment: I have access to the code as a string, but I could also instantiate a ReflectionClass to grab the params names. Really something to consider.

Comment: I'm suggesting after you get everything between the `()` you can use `explode()` with comma as the delimiter. Then just delete the `$` sign.

Comment: Not so simple, as we also have the possibility to have typeHints, but I think this might actually work, I'll write a code for this.

Comment: Well, you can `explode()` with space delimiter. If the param has two parts the first one should be the type.

Comment: That's right, I've done some research right now, we also have the possibility to use preg_split as well. I'm trying with both.

Comment: You could try a simpler regex like `\$\w+` if it's only being applied to lines that are function declarations. https://regex101.com/r/nP7gX9/1

Comment: If I do some restriction to get only the declaration line, this will indeed be fine. The problem is that I have the code for a entire class as a string.

Comment: @TiagoMaia in that case you could add a lookahead such as `\$\w+(?=.*{)` if the opening brace is always on the same line as the function.

Comment: Why would you use regex when you have reflection? It's part of the php core and the only logical solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not regex but it works.

```
$str='public function foo($param1, $param2, $param3) {}';

$str2 = explode(")",explode("(",$str)[1])[0];
$str2 = explode(",",str_replace("$","",$str2));
var_dump($str2);
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b2c2f58ca859e714a169455573ea3fabc8694e84

Answer (score 1):

`\$([a-z[0-9][^,\)]]+)` should work

Explaination :
Search for $, take every alphanumerical value except , or ) and group the result
Tested with [www.regexe.de](http://www.regexe.de)

Result:

```
$param1
$param2
$param3
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that we have more complicated function text description with "type hinting".
Solution using `preg_match_all` function:

```
$func_str = 'public function foo(Closure $param1, $param2 = [], $param3="") {}';

preg_match_all("/\s[$](\w+?)\b/i", $func_str, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => param1
    [1] => param2
    [2] => param3
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize you are asking for a regex solution but there are already 3 regex answers posted and it makes more sense to use `Reflection` for this since it's already built into php. So for those reasons, here is a `Reflection` answer

```
class Bar {
    public function foo($param1, $param2, $param3) {}
}

$class = new ReflectionClass('Bar');
var_dump($class->getMethod('foo')->getParameters());

array(3) {
  [0] =>
  class ReflectionParameter#3 (1) {
    public $name =>
    string(6) "param1"
  }
  [1] =>
  class ReflectionParameter#4 (1) {
    public $name =>
    string(6) "param2"
  }
  [2] =>
  class ReflectionParameter#5 (1) {
    public $name =>
    string(6) "param3"
  }
}
```